# Change Background image with radio button

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the backgroundImage of html with radio button selection. Every radio button has different image. I tried it like:

```
      <input name="BG" id="wood" type="radio" value="" class="bgCollection" />
      <label for="radio">Wood</label>

      <input name="BG" id="steel" type="radio"  class="bgCollection"/>
      <label for="radio">Steel</label>

      <input name="BG" id="metal" type="radio" value="" class="bgCollection"/>
      <label for="radio">Black metal</label>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".bgCollection").change(
               function()
          {
        if($("input#wood").attr("checked"))  
                  {$("html").css('backgroundImage','url(../images/wood.jpg)');}
        if($("input#steel").attr("checked")
                   {$("html").css('backgroundImage','url(../images/BG-steel.jpg)');}
        if($("input#metal").attr("checked"))
                   {$("html").css('backgroundImage','url(images/blackMetal.jpg)');}
       });
  });
```

But this way the background is not changing.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the runnable code with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i have done complete demo for above issue. please check demo link.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp80

**HTML:**

```
<input name="BG" id="wood" type="radio" value="" class="bgCollection" />
<label for="radio">
  Wood
</label>

<input name="BG" id="steel" type="radio"  class="bgCollection"/>
<label for="radio">
  Steel
</label>

<input name="BG" id="metal" type="radio" value="" class="bgCollection"/>
<label for="radio">
  Black metal
</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".bgCollection").change(function() {
        if ($("#wood").is(":checked")) {
            $("body").css('backgroundImage', "url('http://cdnimg.visualizeus.com/thumbs/7f/78/gfx,wood-7f78592c9a6ed3390492c560c5ac6fec_h.jpg')");
        }
        if ($("#steel").is(":checked")) {
            $("body").css('backgroundImage', "url('http://www.aroorsteelcorporation.com/full-images/stainless-steel-834007.jpg')");
        }
        if ($("#metal").is(":checked")) {
            $("body").css('backgroundImage', "url('http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/468538622/Brushed_metal_texture_prepainted_metal.jpg')");
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp80

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right but you have a small syntax error in your jQuery

```
if($("input#steel").attr("checked")
```

**Should be**

```
if($("input#steel").attr("checked"))
```

Notice that missing bracket `)` at the end

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/gtgza/)

But a better way of doing will be using this to get the id and then apply switch to check the Value to set background

[New Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/gtgza/1/)

Comment: thanks for response, i used switch as you advised, but it is not working good, only one of the image works other are still silent.

Comment: Yes.that was working, when i replace the image url b directory path for images that is not working,

Comment: your code was actually 100% correct, mistake was mine, i was using:url(../images/wood.jpg) that was not working, when i replaced that with:url(images/wood.jpg), now it is working. thanks for your time.

Comment: glad you figure it out :) and if my ans and time helped you you can please upvoat the answer

Comment: I tried, as i am new here , i can't... 15 reputations required.

Answer (score 0):

First problem in your code

Your second if conditions is wrong `if($("input#steel").attr("checked")`
It should be `if($("input#steel").attr("checked"))` your closed parenthesis is absent here
then one more thing you should change only the next label means control not the whole html.

So use `.next()` function of jquery Documentation here http://api.jquery.com/next/

I tried this code on jsfiddle test here: http://jsfiddle.net/FB37y/

Answer (score 0):

There is ) missing in the following line of your code:

```
if($("input#steel").attr("checked"))
                   {$("html").css('backgroundImage','url(../images/BG-steel.jpg)');}
```

Comment: is there any modification needed?